# SELECT CURRVAL ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Tengo esta sentencia:

```
SELECT  XXXXX.XXX_XX_XXXXXX_SQ.CURRVAL FROM dual;
```

Me marca este error:

> ORA-08002: sequence  XXXXX.XXX_XX_XXXXXX_SQ.CURRVAL is not yet defined
>   in this session

Tambien intente con esto:

```
SELECT LAST_NUMBER FROM USER_SEQUENCES  WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'XXXXX.XXX_XX_XXXXXX_SQ';
```

No me regresa nada, solo dice `no rows selected`

Como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: tendra que ver con este problema de aca? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26990845/73749

Comment: De memoria, recuerdo que `CURRVAL`está definido solamente después de haber llamado a `NEXTVAL` sobre la secuencia. Si el usuario tiene acceso a la misma, entonces lo que ocurre es que no hay nada en la sesión que haya llamado previamente a `NEXTVAL`. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Posibles causas:

- Que la secuencia de nombre "**XXX_XX_XXXXXX_SQ**" NO exista en el esquema "**XXXXX**"
- Que el usuario con el cual se conecta a la base de datos NO tenga el permiso para "ver" la secuencia "**XXX_XX_XXXXXX_SQ**" que reside en el esquema "**XXXXX" .

Adicionalmente, cambie la sentencia a:

```
SELECT LAST_NUMBER 
FROM ALL_SEQUENCES 
WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME=upper('XXX_XX_XXXXXX_SQ')  /* solo el nombre de la secuencia */
```

La vista **ALL_SEQUENCES** despliega las secuencias a las que tiene acceso el usuario con el cual se conecta a la base de datos Oracle.